# Problemas con funcion de base

Tags: php, hexadecimal

tengo el siguiente problema, necesito convertir este numero a una base 16:

```
entrada: 0000123456789201901131637212310000111010000000100003
salida:  159FFE6FB1986A24BB32DBE5A2A34214B245A6A3
```

revise funciones como dechex base_convert y no me dieron resultado, pierdo informacion debido a que la entrada es muy grande por los digitos que trae (inicialemente lo tengo almacenado como string para no perder los ceros que van por delante).
el resultado que tengo es el siguiente y lo cual es erroneo:

```
$fullCad="0000123456789201901131637212310000111010000000100003";    
dump(  base_convert($fullCad,10,16)   );
    ==>"159ffe6fb1986b00000000000000000000000000"
```

hay alguna forma de obtener el cambio de base? sin que pierda información de la entrada?

php 8.1

Answer (score 2):

Si uno comienza por revisar la [documentación oficial de dec2hex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php#refsect1-function.dechex-description), va a ver que el número más grande que se puede convertir es **4294967295**, así que esa opción no sirve. Por eso siempre hay que comenzar por la documentación oficial de las cosas, hay que creerle a los otros desarrolladores :)

[Esta respuesta](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php#21086) le ha sido útil a otros con el mismo problema, agarra el decimal como string (que ya lo tienes!) y lo convierte "a mano":

```
// Credit: joost at bingopaleis dot com
// Input: A decimal number as a String.
// Output: The equivalent hexadecimal number as a String.
function dec2hex($number)
{
    $hexvalues = array('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7',
               '8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F');
    $hexval = '';
     while($number != '0')
     {
        $hexval = $hexvalues[bcmod($number,'16')].$hexval;
        $number = bcdiv($number,'16',0);
    }
    return $hexval;
}
```

(Usando [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39198528/236345) como referencia. En la misma pregunta hay otras aproximaciones que pueden requerir añádir módulos o compilar PHP con ciertas opciones habilitadas)